# jquery wrap, append, prepend to parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to detect when a certain div element has a height of 0 in order to display a div element with a message.

```
function checkads() 
{
    if ($('#container').height() == 0) 
    {
        $('.wp_bannerize').wrap($('<div id="notice">ENABLE ADS</div>'));
    };
}

$(document).ready(checkads);
```

The above works fine, however, is there anyway to make the script wrap the parent div that is 1 or 2 levels above the child div without having to define the class name of the parent manually "wp_bannerize"

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by *"automatically detect the .wp-bannerize class name"*.

Comment: Side note, you're wrapping your checkads function for no reason, you could simply do `$(document).ready(checkads)`

Comment: indeed is a bit confusing, let me modify the question

Comment: In this script, you have to manually add the class of the element you want to wrap, however is there anyways to make the script wrap a parent div that is 1 or 2 levels above without manually defining it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
function checkads() {
    var $container = $('#container');
    if ($container.height() == 0) {
        $container.parent().wrap($('<div id="notice">ENABLE ADS</div>'));
        // OR $container.parent().parent().wrap($('<div id="notice">ENABLE ADS</div>'));
    }
}
```

Or change your `checkads()` function to:

```
function checkads($current) {
    if ($current.height() == 0) {
        $current.parent().wrap($('<div id="notice">ENABLE ADS</div>'));
    }
}
```

And call it like:

```
checkads($('#container');
checkads($('#container2');
//etc...
```

Comment: @JoseDavidGarciaLlanos That's because your `if` never evaluates to true (I get 20 as the height), check this slightly modified example: http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/MaNdn/2/

Comment: How did you get 20, where can i check

Comment: using Chrome's JavaScript console, but see this other updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/MaNdn/8/

Comment: I am testing it, http://jsfiddle.net/MaNdn/9/ it seems to work, i can see the 3rd parent div being wrapped by looking at the source code but the notice element is not visible in the front end

Comment: Checking out your link, I see it on Chrome 26 and and Firefox 21, it's the one that says "ENABLE ADS2", which browser are you using?

Comment: Actually you are right, It works, the problem is that I am using adblock and this is somehow causing advertisement div elements to behave weird, i checked for orphaned styles and noticed that the wp-bannerize class was somehow being manipulated by my adblock, this is weird.

Comment: Ok i fixed it, what i had to do is to prepend or wrap the new div element outside the element that was being manipulated by the adblocker

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$('#container').parent().parent()` to find the parent of the parent, for example.  You can also use `$('#container').closest('div')` to search through the parent list for the closest `div` (or whatever).  You don't need to know the class name (although you can also use that with `closest`!)

Comment: hey man your answer was fine too, i hope i could have scored both of you